# Install update in android app from my website

Tags: android

I am currently checking the application version in background every 24 hours once in my web server not in android market. If update available that it prompt the user to download the new apk.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(downloadURL);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

The above code open the user browser and start downloading.

I want without opening the browser i need to download the apk file or i need to install the latest apk directly without opening and other application (like browser)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do something like this

// First you need to download apk file.

```
    String extStorageDirectory =        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "APPS");
        folder.mkdir();
        File file = new File(folder, "AnyName."+"apk");
        try {
                file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        /**
         * APKURL is your apk file url(server url)
         */
         DownloadFile("APKURL", file);
```

// the DownloadFile function is

```
      public  void DownloadFile(String fileURL, File directory) {
       try {

            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            URL u = new URL(fileURL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            //c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception in DownloadFile: --------"+e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and after downloading the apk file write this code

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/APPS/" + "AnyName.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(intent);
```

// and give permission in manifest

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

it might help you, i used this for same as your need.

Comment: How i know the file download completed. What are the permission need to give for this

Comment: @Navaneethan use Asynch task for that, in doInBackground() function download the apk file and in onPostExecute() function write code for install the apk file. onPostExecute() function is called after doInBackground() completed.

Comment: @Navaneethan write permission above ie. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: The intent is giving error: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/APPS/attendance.apk exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()