# open my android program after update

Tags: android, updates

I use https://stackoverflow.com/a/14353076/1327384 to update my android program , but after updating my program  it will be closed so I want to reopen it after completing the update process , how can I do that ?

I used this class

```
package services;
    public class PackageChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
         @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            Uri data = intent.getData();
            boolean replacing = intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING, false);

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(ctx, service.class);
            ctx.startService(intent1);
            Log.d("service", "Action: " + intent.getAction());
            Log.d("service", "The DATA: " + data);
            }

    }
```

and this mainfest

```
 <receiver android:name="services.PackageChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />

                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

but I still receive the intent after I start the app manually

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 3):

a) Take a look at [android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED).

b) I believe if your app has a sticky service then this service is restarted after package update.

Comment: what did you mean by a sticky service

Comment: 2forshubi: I meant this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: I try android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED. but it works after I open the program so I want it ti work before that , how can I do that ?

Comment: Try this sticky service. It will restart, so you can do whathever you need in it.

Comment: I try it but it works when I run the program manually , I want it to work after update directly

Comment: this method is working , but I need to make another android application to listen to the intent of installing and replacing my application, but can I put the PackageChangeReceiver in my app not in another app ?

Comment: I think other apps should use PACKAGE_REPLACED broadcast. BTW. Are you sure that you tested correctly PACKAGE_REPLACED? Have you seen this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513825/how-to-correctly-filter-package-replaced-broadcast It looks like their describe exactly your case (listen to your app upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

May be [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) can help? You can set task to start Activity of your app for example in 40 seconds after your apk downloaded and user clicked to install it.

Answer (score 0):

**For API Level 12 & above**

Simply register a broadcast receiver to receive a call **only when your** application package is updated.

```
public class PackageUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //get the launch activity or any activity you want to open 
       Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().
               getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(i);
   }
}
```

Make sure to register the broadcast receiverin the manifest!

```
    <receiver android:name=".receivers.PackageUpdateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Now for the API Level < 12**

You have to register for a generic package update receiver by replacing action name in the manifest as below,

```
MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED with PACKAGE_REPLACED
```

And in the onReceive() method of the BroadcastReceiver check if it's your application's package name,

```
if (intent.getDataString().contains("com.your.app")){
...
}
```